# Gap in between nav bar and top of page

Tags: html, css, navbar

Hi there I was wondering if someone could possibly help me try and fix this gap between my nav bar and top of page, i have checked the css for any margins or anything that could indicate a spacer but simply cannot find it or find a fix, please could somebody possibly help me?

[image]

(For easier view of the website and the problem just [click here](http://equinoxhosting.net) and hover your mouse over home or hosting and you will see the gap between the top and the navbar)

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,300,600,700");

@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:400,300,500,600");

html {
  width: auto;
  overflow-x: hidden !important;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

.dropdown-content a {
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 0px;
}

.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}

.navbrand {
    font-family: sans-serif;
    color: white;
    position: absolute;
    top: 15px;
    left: 90px;
}

li a, .dropbtn {
    display: inline-block;
    color: white;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.navigation-bar {

  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  width: 100%;
}

.navigation-bar ul {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  text-align: right;
}

.navigation-bar li  {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0px;
  height: 27px;
  margin-top: 4px;
  margin-bottom: 4px;
  display: inline;
}

.navigation-bar li a {
  position: relative;
  color: white;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-decoration: none;
  line-height: 70px;
  padding: 5px 35px;

}

#navigation-container {
  width: 1200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 84px;
  z-index: 1;
  position: relative;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: block;
    width: 200px;
}

li a:hover, .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
    background-color: gray;
}

li.dropdown {
    display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: gray
}

#menu {
  float: right;
}

.button {
    position: relative;
    background-color: #1DB2E3;
    border: 2px;
    border-radius: 25px;
    color: white;
    padding: 15px 32px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 16px;
    margin: 4px 2px;
    cursor: pointer;
    top: 70px;
}

}
body {
  font: 14px 'Raleway', Arial, sans-serif;
  line-height: 1.7em;
  font-weight: 300;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  width: auto !important;
  overflow-x: hidden !important;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}

.main {
  background-image: url("../images/bg.png");
  background-size: cover;
  height: 425px;
  width: 100%;
  display: table;
}

.main2 {
  background-image: url("../images/bg.png");
  background-size: cover;
  height: 75px;
  width: 100%;
  display: table;
}

h1, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
  font-weight: 400;
}

.inner {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
  color: #ffffff;
}

.aboutus {
    color: #AAAAAA;
    line-height: 1.5;
    font-size: 16px;
    margin: 0;
    padding-left: 65px;
    padding-right: 65px;
}

.title2 {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  padding: 40px 0 0 0;
  color: #6C6C6C;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0;
}

#button1 {
  border-radius: 100px;
  font-weight: normal;
  padding: 15px 30px;
  border: 0;
}

#button1 {
  box-shadow: 0 5px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
  -webkit-transition: 700ms background ease-in-out;
  transition: 700ms background ease-in-out;
  background: #1DB2E3;
  color: #FFFFFF !important;
}

#button1:hover {
    background: #333E4F;
  }

#main-navigation {
  background: #120D36;
  position: relative;
  border-bottom: 0.5px solid #ffffff;
  min-height: 50px;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: white;
}

a:link, a:hover, a:visited, a:active {
   color: #ffffff;
}

#link1 {
  color: #1DB2E3;
}

hr {
  padding-top: 10px;
}

h2 {
  font-size: 150px;
}

.featureblocks {
  color: #AAAAAA;
  line-height: 1.5;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.featuretitle {
  color: #000000;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding-top: 10px;
}

.featureitem {
  font-weight: 540;
}

.col-md-4 {
  padding-top: 50px;
}

#lastcol {
  padding-bottom: 50px;
}

.bottomtext {
  color: #ffffff;
}

.footer {
  background-image: url("../images/bg.png");
  min-height: 50px;
  min-width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  color: #ffffff;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}

#footer1 {
  padding-top: 13px;
  padding-left: 80px;
}

#footer2 {
 padding-top: 13px;
 padding-right: 80px;
}

.nav .nav-tabs {
  text-align: right;
}

#boetons{
    padding-top: 13px;
    float:right;
    list-style:none;
    background: #120D36;
    position: relative;
    text-align:center;
}
#boetons ul{
    list-style:none;
    background: #120D36;
    position:relative;
}

#boetons li{float:left;position:relative;background:#120D36;}/* ie needs position:relative here*/

#boetons a{
    text-decoration:none;
    background:#120D36;
    float:left;
    color:#fff;
    padding-left: 8px;
    padding-right: 8px;
    text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if IE 8 ]><html class="ie ie8" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 9 ]><html class="ie ie9" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if (gte IE 9)|!(IE)]><!--><html lang="en"><!--<![endif]-->
<html>

<head>
  <!-- Meta Data -->
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="description" content="Equinox Hosting. Affordable Minecraft Hosting for all!">
  <meta name="keywords" content="Hosting, Premium, Minecraft, Equinox">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
  <meta name="author" content="www.davyydevelopment.site">
  <title>Equinox Hosting | Affordable Minecraft Hosting</title>

<!-- Style -->

<!-- Font Awesome -->
<script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/1e0756f001.js"></script>
<!-- CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/custom.css">
<!-- Bootstrap -->
<link rel='stylesheet prefetch' href='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css'>
<!-- Animate -->
<link rel='stylesheet prefetch' href='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/3.5.2/animate.min.css'>
</head>

<body>

<div class="main2">
  <div class="navbrand">
      <p><font size="5">Equinox Hosting</font></p>
  </div>
  <div id="menuwrapper">
<div class="navigation-bar">
<div class="navbar-inner">
  <div id="navigation-container">
    <ul>
          <li><a href="index.html">Home <i class="fa fa-home"></i></a></li>
          <li class="dropdown">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="dropbtn">Hosting <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></a>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="minecraft-hosting.html">Minecraft Hosting</a>
          <li class="dropdown">
              <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="dropbtn">Login <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></a>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="#">Client Area</a>
    <a href="#">Xeon Panel</a>
    <a href="#">Cpanel</a>
            </div>
            </div>
        </li>
      </ul>
  </div>
</div>
 </div>
 </div>

<div class="main">
<div class="inner">
  <h1>HOSTING FOR EVERYONE!</h1>
  <br>
  <h4>Want to get 10% off? Use code <span class="bold">'LAUNCH10'</span></h4>
  <br>
  <button id="button1" type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg active animated pulse infinite"><a href="#">Get started now</a></button>
</div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <h2 class="title2">About us</h2>
  <br>
  <br>
  <strong><p class="aboutus text-center">We are Equinox Hosting, launched in 2017 with a passion for providing our customers with the highest quality services and
    solutions at the lowest prices, affordable for everyone. We always try to answer support tickets &amp; questions as soon
    as possible, so if you do have any questions or queries regarding our services head to
    our <a id="link1" href="contact.html">contact</a> page.</p></strong>

    <br>
    <br>
</div>

<hr>

<div class="features">
    <h2 class="title2">Features</h2>
    <br>
    <br>
    <strong><p class="aboutus text-center">The more affordable approach to stable minecraft server solutions.</p>
            <p class="aboutus text-center">Inexpensive, reliable and feature-rich!</p></strong>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="featureblocks">
  <div class="col-md-4 text-center">
   <img src="images/accelerator.png" alt="accelerator" height="50" width="50">
   <p class="featuretitle">SSD Ready</p>
   <p class="featureitem">All of our servers utilize the latest and fastest SSD technology available.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4 text-center">
    <img src="images/lock.png" alt="lock" height="50" width="50">
    <p class="featuretitle">DDoS Protection</p>
    <p class="featureitem">All of our servers are protected from a range of DDoS attacks via global filtering PoPs.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4 text-center">
    <img src="images/world.png" alt="world" height="50" width="50">
    <p class="featuretitle">24/7 Support</p>
    <p class="featureitem">We proudly present 24hr support for our customers, ensuring good quality. We also offer live support.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4 text-center">
    <img src="images/xeno.png" alt="XenoPanel" height="50" width="50">
    <p class="featuretitle">XenoPanel</p>
    <p class="featureitem">We use the Xenopanel as our Minecraft panel of choice, it allows quick and easy managment for everyone.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4 text-center">
    <img src="images/server.png" alt="server" height="50" width="50">
    <p class="featuretitle">Secure Servers</p>
    <p class="featureitem">We boast that all of our servers have the most cutting edge security available and SSH 256-bit encryption.</p>
  </div>
  <div id="lastcol" class="col-md-4 text-center">
    <img src="images/clock.png" alt="clock" height="50" width="50">
    <p class="featuretitle">Instant Setup</p>
    <p class="featureitem">Your game server will be setup in seconds after payment, truly rapid.</p>
  </div>
</div>
</div>

<section class="footer">
<div id="footer1" class="col-md-6">
  <p>&copy; Equinox Hosting - All Rights Reserved.</p>
</div>
<div id="footer2" align="right" class="col-md-6">
  <nav>
      <a href="#">Terms of service</a>
      <a href="#">Privacy Policy</a>
  </nav>
</section>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I don't see a gap.

Answer (score 2):

try adding the following to your CSS:

```
body {
margin: 0px;
}
```

CSS automatically adds a margin.

Answer (score 0):

custom.css line 58 has `margin-top:4px;` which is causing this problem